# Как сделать эффект левитации в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно добавить эффект левитации при заклинании, использую такой код:
`mob.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * WindForce);`

Но не срабатывает, предполагаю, что мешает компонент NavMeshAgent, как его можно отключить на время или может есть другие варианты?

Взаимодействие моба и заклинание через CapsuleCollider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выключение `NavMeshAgent`:

```
mob_nma = mob.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
mob_nma.enabled = false;
```

Включение соответственно:

```
mob_nma.enabled = true;
```